# How do i install and run Opera browser on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: browser, opera

I have been trying to run Opera on Ubuntu but wine is installing the application but not running the application, any suggestion and how to approach the problem?

Comment: If you still insist in running Opera via Wine, then what error message do you get? Sometimes it helps executing the application from the terminal. You can do that for Wine too with: `wineconsole "C:\Program Files\MyApplication\Executable.exe"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opera provides [native packages to download for most Linux distributions at their website](http://www.opera.com/download/index.dml?platform=linux) and even repositories, so updates are automatically pulled in via package management. There is an article on [Opera in the Ubuntu community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OperaBrowser) providing information beyond just installing.

To add the opera repository with the signing key and install Opera execute the following commands:

```
echo "deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera.list
wget -qO - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install opera
```

I just tried it in my Lucid VM, it works and installs without issues.

[image: Opera in 10.04]

Comment: i'm am having problems synchronizing my opera account with my browser, it's saying something about my username is wrong but when i check my account i don't see anything about username i only see about full name. Is my username and my full name the samething?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a native Linux Install.  Opera has a Linux version available on it's website.

http://www.opera.com/download/index.dml?platform=linux

Before you install any windows application, check to see if there is a Linux version available.

Comment: yes there are Linux version but there don't seen to work....

Comment: Could you be more specific please?

Comment: i got the wrong format, because i'm new to Ubuntu i got confuse with the diferent formats. but now i know it's the DEB format i must use for my Ubuntu...